# Collation for MatSort with languages where alphabetical order is different from Unicode order?

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material, collation

In Norwegian and Danish Alphabets, the correct order of the Norwegian/Danish characters are:

1. Æ
2. Ø
3. Å

However, MatSort uses the Unicode order for these characters:

1. Å (197)
2. Æ (198)
3. Ø (216)

Could collation be implemented somehow to solve this?

Here is a stackblitz with a table that can be sorted by "No." and "Name":

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an1uqc-8mdqns

Here's the data in the table:

```
 {position: 1, name: 'Alpha', description: 'Test123'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Bravo',  description: '0'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Charlie', description: 'aaa'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Delta',  description: ''},
  {position: 5, name: 'Echo',  description: '1'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Foxtrot',  description: '2'},
  {position: 7, name: 'ÆGamma',  description: ''},
  {position: 8, name: 'ØHotel',  description: '3'},
  {position: 9, name: 'ÅIndigo',  description: '1000'},

];
```

The correct way to sort the last three items (ÆGamma, ØHotel and ÅIndigo) according to the Norwegian/Danish alphabet would be:

1. ÆGamma
2. ØHotel
3. ÅIndigo

But MatSort uses the Unicode numbers for these characters and sorts like this instead:

1. ÅIndigo (197)
2. ÆGamma (198)
3. ØHotel (216)

Thanks for reading! :]

Comment: You will need to utilize matSortChange event to implement a custom sort algorithm. The official documentation example shows how to utilize matSortChange https://beta-angular-material-io.firebaseapp.com/components/sort/examples

Comment: I just checked the JavaScript support for localized sorting for these languages, and language code 'da' gives you the sorting you want, but 'no' doesn't - with 'no', the sorting is `["ÆGamma", "ÅIndigo", "ØHotel"]`.

Comment: @kshetline is it possible to use localized sorting with MatSort?

Comment: As far as I can tell, only @Alexander Staroselsky's suggestion would help you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [matSortChange](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api) to implement a custom sort, in this case a localized sort. This can be done using [String.prototype.localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with language identifier `da-DK`:

Template:

```
<table
  mat-table [dataSource]="sortedData"
  matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)"
  class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Component:

```
sortData(sort: Sort) {
  const data = ELEMENT_DATA.slice();
  if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
    this.sortedData = data;
    return;
  }

  this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
    const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
    switch (sort.active) {
      case 'position': return compareNumber(a.position, b.position, isAsc);
      case 'name': return compareString(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
      case 'description': return compareString(a.description, b.description, isAsc);
      default: return 0;
    }
  });
}

// ...

function compareNumber(a: number, b: number, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}

function compareString(a: string, b: string, isAsc: boolean) {
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'da-DK') * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an1uqc-jv1s6z) in action.

The sorted results are as follows:

```
1 Alpha
// ...
6 Foxtrot
7 ÆGamma
8 ØHotel
9 ÅIndigo
```

Then in reverse:

```
9 ÅIndigo
8 ØHotel
7 ÆGamma
6 Foxtrot
// ...
1 Alpha
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Fantastic! I also asked about this in the Angular GitHub, and they did not know, so I'd repost your example here so more people can see this! ;)
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16923

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue when working with German umlauts. My solution using MatTableDataSource, is simply defining a custom sortData() implementation:

```
@ViewChildren(MatSort) public matSortQueryList: QueryList<MatSort>;

public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<CUSTOMTYPE> = new MatTableDataSource<CUSTOMTYPE>([]);
private readonly defColl = new Intl.Collator('de');
private readonly _subs = new Subscription();

public ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.data = CUSTOMDATA[];
  
  this._subs.add(
    this.matSortQueryList.changes.subscribe(elems => {
      if (elems.length && !this.dataSource.sort) {
        this.dataSource.sort = elems.first;
      }
    })
  );
  
  this.dataSource.sortData = (data: CUSTOMTYPE[], sort: MatSort) => {
    const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
      return this.defColl.compare(a.CUSTOMPROPERTY as string, b.CUSTOMPROPERTY as string);
    });

    return sort.direction === 'desc' ? sorted.reverse() : sorted;
  }
}
```

Besides, I'd recommend using Intl.Collator - it's much faster than localeCompare.